# Validation of properties that require the values of other properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-validation

So I have checked out this answer [ASP:NET MVC 4 dynamic validation of a property depending of the current value of another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060246/aspnet-mvc-4-dynamic-validation-of-a-property-depending-of-the-current-value-of) and it does not cover the issue I am having.

I am using **server side** validation. I have a requirement that...

> A value is only required if another property is specified

### Issue

MVC binds each property and calls each validator on that property as it binds them. If I am dependent on multiple properties being set when I check `validationContext.ObjectInstance.[MY_DEPENDENT_PROPERTY]` there is a possibility that those dependent properties have not been bound yet.

What I need is a validation attribute that validates **after** binding - if that even exists.

---

So here is a simple example to explain my situation (not intended to be executed as it will more than likely be fine since the issue has to do with binding order)

### My model

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string ResidentialAddress { get; set; }

    public bool PostalIsTheSameAsResidential { get; set; }

    // will only be required if PostalIsTheSameAsResidential is false.
    // see the static method below and RequiredIfAttribute
    [RequiredIf(typeof(Address), nameof(PostalRequiredIfNotSameAsResidential)]
    public string PostalAddress { get; set; }

    public static bool PostalRequiredIfNotSameAsResidential(Address model)
    {
        return !model.PostalIsTheSameAsResidential;
    }
}
```

### My validator

Essentially what happens here is it calls the static method on the model to see whether it should validate.

```
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    private readonly MethodInfo _validationMethod;
    public override bool RequiresValidationContext => true;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(Type type, string methodName)
    {
        this._validationMethod = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        if (this._validationMethod == null)
        {
            throw new MethodAccessException($"The validation method '{methodName}' does not exist on type '{type}");
        }
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;

        var parameters = this._validationMethod.GetParameters();
        var returnType = this._validationMethod.ReturnType;

        if (returnType == typeof(bool) && parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == validationContext.ObjectType)
        {
            if ((bool)_validationMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { validationContext.ObjectInstance }))
            {
                if (!base.IsValid(value))
                {
                    string[] memberNames;
                    if (validationContext.MemberName == null)
                    {
                        memberNames = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        memberNames = new string[1];
                        memberNames[0] = validationContext.MemberName;
                    }
                    result = new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), memberNames);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        var expectedFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(validationContext.ObjectType, typeof(bool));
        throw new MethodAccessException($"The validation method '{this._validationMethod}' does not have the correct definition. Expected '{expectedFuncType}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you do not want client side validation as well as server side validation. You can use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfFalse("PostalIsTheSameAsResidential")]` or similar validation attribute (or you can easily write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Note also that you should be inheriting from `ValidationAttribute`, not `RequiredAttribute`

Comment: And your assumptions about the way binding and validation work are incorrect - the `validationContext` parameter of the `IsValid()` method contains all the information about the property values you need - `var property = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("PostalIsTheSameAsResidential "); var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);` will return the value of your `bool` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your second comment was the issue. I Will post a write up as an answer

Comment: You should be taking note of the other 2 as well (your writing twice as much code as necessary to do this)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not sure why you think I am writing twice as much code as needed... the answer to your first comment is that I need to run C# code in my validation. The actual validation is way, way more complex than the example I gave. The example's purpose was to be easy to read and follow. Your third comment does not fit my use case at all as I need the full object - not just a single property.

Comment: You do get the 'full object' (you can get all the properties and values from `validationContext`. Not sure what you mean _the answer to your first comment is that I need to run C# code in my validation_? I was just commenting on why you do not also implement `IClientValidatable` and get client side validation as well as the server side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue that I was having was that I was inheriting from the `RequiredAttribute`. Internally MVC handles this attribute differently to everything else.

When the Model Binder is looping through the properties, it gets the `RequiredAttribute`s and executes them at the same time...

```
// System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.SetProperty
....
    ModelValidator modelValidator = (from v in ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(modelMetadata, controllerContext)
        where v.IsRequired
        select v).FirstOrDefault<ModelValidator>();
        if (modelValidator != null)
        {
            foreach (ModelValidationResult current in modelValidator.Validate(bindingContext.Model))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(key, current.Message);
            }
        }
....
```

That `v.IsRequired` actually resolves to a line that tests if the current attribute is a `RequiredAttribute` and will validate it there, in the current, incomplete model state.

By inheriting from `ValidationAttribute` it ran the validations after the model had been built and solved my issue.

---

Thanks to @StephenMuecke for prompting me with this.